# Errors thrown when my python-telegram-bot is doing run_polling are not logged to console

Tags: python, telegram, python-unittest, python-telegram-bot, long-polling

I'm trying to test my telegram bot made with `python-telegram-bot` using `unittest`. The problem is that after I do `updater.run_polling()`, any errors raised thereafter simply cause the console to freeze here:

```
EWARNING:telegram.ext.Application:Fetching updates got a asyncio.CancelledError. Ignoring as this task may onlybe closed via `Application.stop`.
DEBUG:telegram.ext.Updater:Network loop retry getting Updates was cancelled
```

After I do Ctrl + C, it then shows this traceback, with no mention of the actual error:

```
EWARNING:telegram.ext.Application:Fetching updates got a asyncio.CancelledError. Ignoring as this task may onlybe closed via `Application.stop`.
DEBUG:telegram.ext.Updater:Network loop retry getting Updates was cancelled
^CDEBUG:asyncio:Close <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=True>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathan/development/python/ptbtest/examples/test_my.py", line 32, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/main.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/main.py", line 274, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/runner.py", line 217, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/case.py", line 678, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/async_case.py", line 133, in run
    self._tearDownAsyncioRunner()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/async_case.py", line 126, in _tearDownAsyncioRunner
    runner.close()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 71, in close
    _cancel_all_tasks(loop)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 201, in _cancel_all_tasks
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks.gather(*to_cancel, return_exceptions=True))
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 640, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1881, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/selectors.py", line 561, in select
    kev_list = self._selector.control(None, max_ev, timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt
ERROR:asyncio:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
source_traceback: Object created at (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathan/development/python/ptbtest/examples/test_my.py", line 32, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/main.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/main.py", line 274, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/runner.py", line 217, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/case.py", line 678, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/async_case.py", line 131, in run
    return super().run(result)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/case.py", line 623, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/async_case.py", line 90, in _callTestMethod
    if self._callMaybeAsync(method) is not None:
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/unittest/async_case.py", line 112, in _callMaybeAsync
    return self._asyncioRunner.run(
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 640, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1911, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/Users/nathan/development/python/ptbtest/examples/test_my.py", line 23, in test
    await application.start()
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/venvptbtest-3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 566, in start
    self.__update_fetcher_task = asyncio.create_task(
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 374, in create_task
    task = loop.create_task(coro)
task: <Task cancelling name='Task-6' coro=<Application._update_fetcher() running at /Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/venvptbtest-3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py:1050> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()] created at /Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py:427> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at /Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py:754] created at /Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py:374>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Application._update_fetcher at 0x10e9b0c80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/venvptbtest-3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1050, in _update_fetcher
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/queues.py", line 160, in get
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 761, in call_soon
  File "/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

How do I make it show me the errors? I tried adding an error handler but to no avail (it doesn't print anything):

```py
def error_handler(update, context):
    print('ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR')
    print(context)

...

application.add_error_handler(error_handler)
```

My full code:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import unittest
import pytest
from telegram.ext import Application
import logging

def error_handler(update, context):
    print('ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR')
    print(context)

class TestConversationbot2(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test(self):
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
        application = (
            Application
            .builder()
            .token('MY_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN')
            .build()
            )
        application.add_error_handler(error_handler)
        await application.initialize()
        await application.start()
        await application.updater.start_polling()
        raise BaseException('my error')
        await application.updater.stop()
        await application.stop()
        await application.shutdown()
        return None
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```